# Eclipse "Selected Project" not functioning as expected

Tags: eclipse

I'm running into an issue in Eclipse where the editor pane is not linked to the project in the `Package Explorer` window.  For instance, if I click on a project in the package explorer and then open a `Problems` window that is set to `Configure Contents` > uncheck `Show all items` > set `Scope` to `On any element in same project`, it will show any applicable errors or warnings for just that project, but as soon as I open one of the files with an error/warning in it, in the editor pane, the problems list goes blank as the editor pane does not appear to link the active tab to its project.  Simply clicking the `Package Explorer` window will then repopulate the `problems` tab until focus goes back to the editor window/tab.

This used to work with older versions of Eclipse, but ever since I updated Eclipse, it no longer does this and I don't recall which version it was that I had been using.  I've also downloaded a completely clean copy of Eclipse Luna (latest version) and simply imported the old projects and still the same issue.

Is there any way to change it so the active tab in the editor points to its associated project?  It's quite frustrating having to click the `Package Explorer` window every time I want to look at a list of problems or tasks for a specific project.

Comment: As a side note; the "Link to editor" button does nothing more than expand the package explorer to the file I have selected in the editor... the problems list still does not populate correctly using this option unless the package explorer is the primary focus.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue... sort of.  Apparently, if you minimize the problems tab, then try to access it via the minimized icon for the tab, it loses the correct focusing to tell you what the problems are.  My previous version was setup in exactly the same way and had no issues, so they must have changed something that broke this.  Going to look at submitting this to the Eclipse team, as a bug.